# How to configure laravel-mix to compile "compass scss"

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, laravel-5, compass-sass

I've just installed and setup Laravel 5.4 to compile scss, but it do not supports "compass scss". Searching for a solution leads me to [Question in Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/using-compass-with-laravel-mix), but without any proper answer. I believe there should be some way to do this using the webpack.mix.js, but couldn't find any.

A link to documentation and at least some snippet of configuration would be helpful. Thanks.

**Pleae note:** I'm using laravel 5.4 which uses `Laravel-Mix` not `Laravel-Elixir`.